# How to reduce amount of memory taken by function pointers in structs?

Tags: c, oop, function-pointers, memory-optimization

I'm trying to implement some kind of OOP in C. I have a struct Foo that has a funcion pointer to some function:

```
struct Foo
{
    void (*func)();
};
```

The problem here is that every instance of this type will have this pointer which takes space and if I were to add more function pointers (and for a typical struct I usually create a lot of them) them my program will consume way more memory. What is the generally accepted way to get around this increased memory consumption? How do object-oriented languages handle this? And how do implement that in C?

Comment: How would this differ from having a pointer to a string, like `char *string;`, as a member? Both are pointers. Both need space. Even plain `int` members take up space in your structure (just like any variable, even local variables inside your function, or function arguments, take up space), there's really no way around that.

Comment: If you have a lot of objects that have the same set of functions you could create a separate struct for only the function pointers and refer to that. That way each instance of a class does not need a pointer to every function

Comment: If it's really essential to save memory, you could store the function pointers in a lookup table and store the index in the struct.

Comment: Or are you worried that pointers to functions will make a copy of the function code itself? Then no that won't happen. There will only be only one function, but you can have many pointers to that single function. Again it's just like any other pointer. For example if you have a string there will be only one string but perhaps many pointers to it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude no, I'm worried exactly about space taken by pointers.

Comment: @thebusybee yes, that should work. With this intermediate call, the code becomes even more complex, but, I suppose, that's the best I can have.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Re “How would this differ from having a pointer to a string, like `char *string;`, as a member?”: The issue is that the function pointers are identical for every instance of the base class, and therefore having multiple copies of them, one in each instance, is wasteful.

Comment: @SunofAbeach -  I was working on something that may have helped, but too late in posting before this was closed.  Essentially constructing a pointer to array of function pointers as a member of a struct.  The size of that struct would be the size of a single pointer, even though it would provided the functionality of several function pointers.  The down side is there would be memory allocation required before the functionality of function pointers could be accessed.  Depending on what you are looking for, I thought it might be interesting to consider.  If interested in more info, comment me.

Comment: @EricPostpischil But that could still apply for all members of a "base class", pointers or not.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Yes, so? It is the problem OP seeks to solve or mitigate.

Comment: @SunofAbeach Are you targeting an embedded system where memory is a concern? Because otherwise it seems like a premature "optimization" to me. And if you have so many pointers it becomes a problem I'd argue that the design might be flawed. (This hasn't really been a major problem on mainstream PC-like systems since well before sub-GiB systems.)

Comment: @SunofAbeach Anyway, you can use one structure for function pointers, create one single instance of that structure, and make all instances of the actual "class" have a pointer to this single function structure. Then each "object" will only add memory for a single pointer. It will however add one more indirection to be able to call the functions. It's the age-old compromise between memory and CPU clock cycles.